# Быстро разряжается ноут под ОС Linux Mint

Tags: linux, энергосбережение

Поломка жёсткого диска привела к установке новой операционной системы, с Windows 8.1 на Linux 18.3 (Mint Cinnamone). И, если до этого я мог спокойно использовать ноутбук без подключения к сети около 1,5-2 часов в условиях "марш броска" для батареи, то сейчас устройство засыпает уже через минут 20 использования. 
 Подскажите, что делать, учитывая мой небольшой опыт использования линуксоидов? Программы для оптимизации работы аккумулятора, ресурсы с полезной информацией на эту тему - всё пойдёт в копилку.

Comment: 1. Пробовать последнее ядро из ванильных, linux-next, смотреть, что там за ситуация. 2. Запустить *powertop* и крутить ручки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, с линуксом на ноутбуках бывает проблема, когда он использует дискретную видеокарту на постоянной основе. В зависимости от того, `nvidia` у вас или `amd`, нужно установить соответствующий софт, который будет переключать дискретную видеокарту на встроенную и наоборот.

С `amd` я не сталкивался, но вот для `nvidia` посмотрите в сторону `nvidia prime` или `bumblebee`.

UPD: Если не ошибаюсь, если на минте через менеджер драйверов устанавливать драйвера на дискретную `nvidia`, то он поставит `nvidia-prime`.

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/nvidia-prime

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee